# Is it possible to get a profile url on AWS CodeCommit like on Github?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Many programmers like to share all their public repos where their code is stored and they can give their unique Github URL to everyone who's interested in it; like potential employers.

If someone sets up an AWS account and AWS CodeCommit, can he then get such a profile URL for himself there also? (Or is AWS CodeCommit more designed for your personal version control etc. and not having a real profile for others?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CodeCommit is not designed for public anonymous access. Access to CodeCommit requires AWS credentials. The purpose of CodeCommit is for teams to be able to work together and not to provide a public repository.